# How to deal with variable length output units in output dense layer?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras to build my architecture.

The regression problem I am trying to solve has outputs different for different training samples.

For instance, for 1st training sample, I have output as `[16,3]` for 2nd training sample it is `[6]`. I am unable to find a solution about how to assign units to output dense layer based on this type of output. You can interpret the output as having `y_train` having shape [no. of samples, columns(depending on how many outputs do specific training sample has)].

I have tried to fetch each and every input from `y_train`, so that I would have assign the length of this input to output dense layer as units, e.g. as for 1st training sample, we have `[16,3]` as output (input in `y_train` to predict for 1st training sample), I am planning to set output dense layer's unit as 2 and so on. but I even don't know how to fetch this and assign it to output dense layer's unit.

Can anybody help me on this variable length output problem?

Comment: A dense neural network is not really equipped to have variable length outputs. Maybe if you described your problem more clearly someone can help find a way to use a dense neural network for it. As I don't think this problem is a coding problem, more of a data science problem, I think it belongs more on data science or cross validated stack exchanges.

Comment: If you want to definitely use dense, then you must reshape all your data to single dimension, and provide padding for the data for which the the data isn't available. But it is going to take a hit on your accuracy. As @enumaris mentioned, if you could explain the scenario, then we can help out with some solution

Comment: @venkata krishnan Suppose I have input data like this: 1st training sample is 1D as [1,2,3,4,5] and 2nd training sample is 2D, which I have converted to 1D so that I can give this sample as one of the inputs to MLP, and so on. Moreover, I want my model to have one dense unit in the output dense layer for 1D and 2 units for 2D. I know I will have to give my data in the form of 1D as input to my MLP model, but want my MLP model to give variable length output as stated above. Please help.